# checking the ace editor in the onbeforeunload to see if changes were made

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to use the `$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){});` and `editor.session.getUndoManager().isClean();` in the ace editor to check if the user made changes to a document but didn't click the submit button but for some reason it doesn't work  Here's the code:

```
editor.on('change', function(Isclean ) {
        var Isclean = editor.session.getUndoManager().isClean();
    });
var submitting = false;

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    if (submitting == false && Isclean == false) {
            return "You have made some changes in the editor.";
    };
});
```

But for whatever reason Isclean always returns a boolean of true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this task I did:

```
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
    editor.session.getUndoManager().markClean();
});
```

I was pre-loading some Json into the editor so unless i called `editor.session.getUndoManager().markClean();` as the last thing to load (and it HAS to be the last thing to load), it would always boolean to false.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with the code. In your 'change' event handler, the function argument and the local variable are both called `Isclean`.

Secondly, the `Isclean` variable is not visible to your 'beforeunload' event handler.

Comment: So how do I pass the local variable to the on beforeunload?